# How to delete OneDrive folder with Logic Apps?

Tags: azure, onedrive, azure-logic-apps

What I want to do is to delete a OneDrive Folder I'm creating with a file inside. So I want to Delete both folder and file. Deleting the file is simple, just with Delete File (ID) it deletes it, but what about the folder?

[image]

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt seem the [OneDrive connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/onedriveconnector/) offers a delete folder option. You would need to build something custom to achieve this.